# Does Tekkit support 1.5.x?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-tekkit

I'd like to play Tekkit. I'd also like to play it on 1.5.x.

Is this possible? Does Tekkit support 1.5.x?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**, at least, not currently:

> Tekkit Classic is a fully Bukkit-ized version of Tekkit running Minecraft 1.2.5. We will continue to support Tekkit Clasic until a solid and reliable replacement for ForgeBukkit comes around.

The Technic Platform also offers Tekkit Lite which appears to have a similar mod list, but without the Bukkit portion, and the Feed The Beast packs also include similar mods, but the Tekkit that was in 1.2.5 is still in 1.2.5 until ForgeBukkit can be replaced.

Comment: The ridiculously poorly named Tekkit Lite actually has more mods; the "Lite" just means no Bukkit support. I believe it runs on 1.4.7 now (which makes the answer still "No" anyway).